# Establishing the number of times element appears in mongodb collection before mapreduce

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Thanks for the help in advance.

I have the following in a mongodb collection

```
{

id: 12345,
userid: 9876,
CompName: PC-537,
LogonTime: 2015-07-1,
SessionName: Session1
}
```

What i am trying to do is Mapreduce the database down to where i can see how many sessions were allocated to each comp name, so instead of the comp name appearing multiple times in the collection, it will appear once, with the sessions associated with it appearing as values

Can someone please give me some pointers? I know how to mapreduce when using numbers (for example rainfall: 9mm) and having that tally up, but when its text how can i find reduce it so the PC's only appear once, and also either list all the sessions they had and the total sessions they had.

What I have tried so far is the following

```
var mapFunc = function() {
                       emit(this.CompName, this.SessionName);
                   };

var reduceFunc = function(keyComp, keySession) {
                          return Array.sum(keySession);
                      };


db.compcollection.mapReduce(
                     mapFunc,
                     reduceFunc,
                     { out: "comp2" }
                   )
```

This gave me a result of the database reducing down to the session name not the CompName and also did not give a numeric count. So basically it gave me all the machines associated with a sessionname, not the reverse (which is what i want)

Can someone please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs this in the future i have figured this out, see code below

```
var mapper = function() { 
emit(this.CompName, 1);
};

var reducer = function(compname, counter) {
return Array.sum(count);
};


db.compcollection.mapReduce(mapper, reducer, { out: "comp15" }

 )
```